# How to check for hidden corruptions

Tags: sqlite

I have observed the following behavior:

- I have a certain database file, let's call it *original*. If I perform some updates to it (mostly insertions), queries starts failing at certain step with error "database disk image is malformed". It reproduces at each try.
- if I dump to sql and recreate the original database, and repeat the same updates, the error does not happen.
- query "PRAGMA integrity_check" does not show any errors at the original database.

This seems to mean that the original database have some corruption which is invisible to the integrity_check. Question is: are there more check which I could use to find such hidden corruptions?

Unfortunately I cannot share the data.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about figuring out what's messing with the database, because that shouldn't be happening. Make sure you're not doing anything in [this list](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not all types of corruptions are detectable.  "PRAGMA integrity_check" does its best, and I think is probably about as good as you do.